# Switch between objects in nested array with button (vanillaJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I would like to be able to switch between, or at least display the next object in a nested array of objects by clicking a button.

I have been able to do this with a single array, but when it's a nested array I can't figure it out. Right now, the index of the infoList-array item to be displayed is just set to 0, to test the code.

What I  want to accomplish:

1. Load a room and show the text of the first infoList-array object
2. Click the nextButton to show next infoList object's text
3. When I get to the last object of the infoList-array, hide the nextButton

Please take a look at my code below (I'm VERY new with JS so there might be some other, more clever way than mine to solve this)

```
const roomInfoElement = document.getElementById('room-info')

function loadRoom(roomId) {

  let i = 0

  const currentRoom = roomList.find(currentRoom => currentRoom.id === roomId)
  const roomInfo = currentRoom.infoList[i].text
  roomInfoElement.innerText = roomInfo

  const nextButton = document.createElement('button')
  nextButton.innerText = 'Show next object'
  roomInfoElement.appendChild(nextButton)
  nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => showNext() )
}

function showNext() { 
  console.log('test') // This is just to test
    }

const roomList = [
  {
    roomId: 1,
    infoList: [
      {
        text: 'This is the first info object in room 1'
      },
      {
        text: 'This is the second info object in room 1'
      },
      {
        text: 'This is the third info object in room 1'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    info: 'This is the second room',
    optionList: [
      {
        text: 'Go back to room 1',
        nextRoom: 1
      },
      {
        text: 'Go to room 3', 
        nextRoom: 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Is this all the code? It seems a little incomplete? How are you, for example, calling the `loadRoom` function?

Comment: Its not all the code, but all the code thats I thought was relevant for my question. 

loadRoom(1) is called in function gameInit() and then again when the user is selecting an option to go to another room. But this code is left out.

Comment: You'll need to save the state of the index in some type of variable.